# Apex:repeat issue : returns unexpected output

Tags: visualforce, trigger, datatable.js

i've a list which has been assigned to a SOQL query result and it returns one object. : using a debug log it is confirmed.

I've used dataTables JQuery pluging too.

But when i assign to a apex:repeat it returns 3 values, 2 of them are empty and one is the actual value.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!SOs}" var="SOItem" >
<tr>
       <td>{!SOItem.Buyer__r.name}</td>
 </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Did you try to see, size of that array/list "Sos'? Please check before the SOQL and and after SOQL. It would be more better, if you add your controller code here.

Comment: yes. I even used size inside the apex too , it still returns 1 . 
                                 <apex:repeat value="{!SOs}" var="SOItem" >
                                     <tr>
                                         <td>{!SOs.size}</td>
                                     </tr>
                                 </apex:repeat>

Comment: well, try to use its length on VF page before the repeat.  There might be some code in your controller/vf's JS which is affecting/adding garbage to SOs.

Comment: May i know how to use the length of List for repeat?

Comment: {!Sos.size} -> either try to print in console.log or add it in alert() of JS.

Comment: I used SOs.size and it gives result as 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48108/discussion-between-ysr-shk-and-chathura).